# How to override how my classes property is rendering the JSON for my order model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am currently doing this in my controller action:

```
render json: order.to_json(:include => [items: {include: [products: {include: [:inventory]}]}])
```

Now I am moving this over to a richer object like this:

```
class OrderResponse
  attr_accessor :success, :errors, :order, :users
  def initialize(success, errors)
    @success = success
    @errors = errors
  end

end
```

The problem now is that it doesn't render all the inner data of the order model.
The json now has only the order attributes since I am not calling the :includes now.

```
response = OrderResponse.new(true, [])
response.order = order
response.user = user

render json: response
```

How can I override how the order is being converted to json now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you can create .html templates using the ERB templating language (or others), you can use the [jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) DSL to render complex json responses.

OrdersController:

```
@response = OrderResponse.new(true, [])
render :response, formats: [:json]
```

views/orders/response.json.jbuilder

```
json.call @response, :id
json.user do
  json.extract! @response.user, :id, :created_at # ...
end
json.order do
  json.extract! @response.order, :id, :created_at # ...
end
```

Comment: How would I use jbuilder to render this? ```order.to_json(:include => [items: {include: [products: {include: [:inventory]}]}])```  I can only do a single item like ```json.order @response.order``` but I am not sure how to dig into all the inner collections.

Comment: You will have to read the docs for ```json.array!``` for example ```json.items json.array! @response.items, :id, :name # ...```